# Non-uniform lattices and parabolic subgroups in Lie groups

Tags: lie-groups, lattices

Let $G$ be a semisimple connected Lie group and let $\Lambda < G$ be a non-uniform irreducible lattice.

How does it follows that there exists a minimal parabolic subgroup $P$ of $G$ such that the unipotent radical of $P$ intersects $\Lambda$  in a lattice?

Comment: Do you mean the unipotent radical? Parabolic subgroups are not unimodular...

Comment: Yes – thank you for that correction! Edited the question.

Comment: Still not true, as obviously one has uniform lattices, even in $SL_{2}$, and so there is no closed $Rad_{U}(P)$-orbits, or in simpler words - your lattice does not contain any non-trivial unipotents.
In general one wants some compatibility of the Lie/alg group structure and the lattice, the most common one is to assume the lattice is arithmetic and to consider $\mathbb{Q}$-parabolics. The magic words here are $\mathbb{Q}$-rank vs $\mathbb{R}$-rank.

Comment: Sorry – I forgot to add non-uniform, which is corrected now. The claim that such a minimal parabolic exists for a non-uniform lattice is made in Eskin-Margulis.

Comment: There are at-least 3 different papers of Eskin and Margulis. Anyhow if it is the one I am thinking about, for rank 1 it follows from Garland-Ragunathan, for higher rank, you can use arithemeticity (finiteness of class number, etc).

Comment: Non-uniform just means $\mathbf{Q}$-rank $\ge 1$. If $G$ is $\mathbf{Q}$-defined and not quasi-split with $\Gamma=G(\mathbf{Z})$, if I'm correct no minimal parabolic is a $\mathbf{Q}$-defined subgroup and hence I expect the answer is negative.

Comment: I think that there is some confusion about notations here. In the arithmetic case when $G$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-group, I think that the answer should be yes, if you take a minimal parabolic defined over $\mathbb{Q}$, which is different than a "minimal parabolic" in the definition of a quasi-split group.

Comment: Since $G$ is defined as a connected Lie group, minimal parabolic should probably be interpreted as minimal parabolic among $\mathbf{R}$-subgroups. For this reason one should probably pick an example of a $\mathbf{Q}$-group that is $\mathbf{R}$-split with small $\mathbf{Q}$-rank.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments! I'm nonetheless getting confused. My question refers to the paper "Recurrence Properties of Random Walks on Finite Volume Homogeneous Manifolds", which can be downloaded from Eskin's homepage. On page 1 they define that a parabolic subgroup $P$ is called $\Lambda$-rational if the unipotent radical of $P$ intersects $\Lambda$ in a lattice. Then on page 9, they use the existence of a $\Lambda$-rational minimal parabolic subgroup of G, if $G$ is a s.s. Lie group and $\Lambda$ a non-uniform irreducible lattice. How does it follows that such a $P$ exists?

Comment: @ConstantinK then this is trivial: just pick one minimal among the $\Lambda$-rational parabolic subgroups. The point is that it is not minimal among the parabolic subgroups in the ambient Lie group, in general.

Comment: Just to add: On page 4 that they claim if $G$ has rank 1, then since $\Lambda$ is non-uniform there exists a $\Lambda$-rational minimal parabolic subgroup $P$ of $G$. This contradics some of the above claims and if I understand correctly they really want that $P$ is minimal among all the parabolic subgroups (I think they also need that later on in the paper). How does this follow excactly? I looked at Garland-Ragunathan as Asaf suggested, yet it is not immediatly clear to me where in that paper the claim is proved.